# Return value from function scope

Tags: node.js

Can I return the value of an object from a function?

I have a service layer that has the business logic, and I am trying to call a repository layer to retrieve data from MongoDB.

The problem is:

```
 ClienteGet(req) {
        var response;

        repo.get(req.params.clienteId, (err, response) => {
            console.log(response); -> here I have the correct data
        });

        console.log(response); -> only shows undefined
        return response;
    };
```

This is my repository method:

```
get(clienteId, res) {
       mongoose.model('Cliente').findById(clienteId, res);
   };
```

ClienteGet needs to return the response to the controller, to be shown on the FrontEnd.

I can I acess the response outside of the function scope?

EDIT:

Repository method

```
    get(clienteId, res) {
        mongoose.model('Cliente').findById(clienteId, res);
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
 ClienteGet async (req) {
        let response;

        await repo.get(req.params.clienteId, (err, res) => {
            response = res;
        });

        return response;
    };
```

Comment: Didn't work mate, but thank you !

Comment: edited my answer, does that work?

Comment: No, still retrieves undefined.

Comment: Your repository method is not returning anything btw.

Comment: Yes, it is.
Can't do that, curley are needed in that place.

Comment: Can you edit your quesiton with more code, because your repository snippet is definitely not returning anything.

Comment: Mate, if I send an Id and I receive the object in the console.log inside the repo.get, why do you say is not returning anything?